# apple receipt validation woes

Tags: ios, app-store, receipt-validation

Folks,
  Trying to validate a receipt on the server, and Apple documentations is vague at best.

From the docs last paragraph (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html):

`The values of the latest_receipt and latest_receipt_info keys are useful when checking whether an auto-renewable subscription is currently active. By providing any transaction receipt for the subscription and checking these values, you can get information about the currently-active subscription period. If the receipt being validated is for the latest renewal, the value for latest_receipt is the same as receipt-data (in the request) and the value for latest_receipt_info is the same as receipt.`

I check if the receipt string that the phone sent matches the `data.latest_receipt` that I get back from apple, and it does not!

When looking at the JSON object that I get back from apple, the objects inside the `latest_receipt_info` and `receipt` are different as well.

Can someone please tell me their experience, and how does one validate that the receipt is valid?

Comment: Here is a link to gist with the JSON response: https://gist.github.com/vasiliyb/23b5ac1fb36c6fd50006

Answer (score 0):

This last paragraph is most likely about latest receipt styles. While you use the old one.